# HTTPS: Certificate is not signed for askubuntu.com

Tags: support

If I try to access https://askubuntu.com, the certificate is signed for *.stackexchange.com instead of askubuntu.com.

Can this be fixed for a better HTTPS access?

Comment: Does it work on other stack sites with their own domain?

Comment: @izx No, not even StackOverflow.

Comment: I added a comment on the thread referenced by @Zypher.  I don't think the stack network would have issues getting a signing certificate given it has *relatively* rapid changes in domain names...and plans for more in the future.  It would just make sense to have a signing certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently We do not support connecting to our sites via SSL. We are starting to slowly work on this, but it is not a high priority project for us.

Please See [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) for more information